# State variable not updated when changed in another View

Tags: swiftui

I want to better understand binding data across view, so I made this demo app

First View - if *isShowing* is true, navigating to *SecondView* (binding *value*)

```
struct ParentView: View {

@State var isShowing = false
@State var value = 5

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        if value != 5 {
            ThirdView(isShowing: $isShowing)
        } else {
            NavigationLink(isActive: $isShowing) {
                SecondView(value: $value)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to second view")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Second view - updating *ParentView* value

```
struct SecondView: View {

@Binding var value: Int
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button {
            value = 5
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } label: {
            Text("Return 5")
        }
        
        Button {
            value = 1
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } label: {
            Text("Return 1")
        }
    }

}
}
```

ThirdView - showing in *FirstView* in case *value* is not 5

```
struct ThirdView: View {

@Binding var isShowing: Bool

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Button {
            isShowing.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Its a problem... Go to second view")
        }
    }
}
}
```

I tried to toggle *isShowing* in *ThirdView* so it can open *SecondView* to update *value* again.

But when button is clicked in *ThirdView*, it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have things set up, it won't change. When `value != 5`, your `NavigationLink does not exist in the view. Instead, you want to trigger it programmatically like this:

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @State var isShowing = false
    @State var value = 5

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(value.description)
            if value != 5 {
                ThirdView(isShowing: $isShowing)
            } else {
                // Change out the NavigationLink for a button that sets isShowing.
                Button {
                    isShowing = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to second view")
                }
            }
            }
            // By placing it in the background, it is always available to be triggered.
            .background(
                NavigationLink(isActive: $isShowing) {
                    SecondView(value: $value)
                } label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, you don't need to toggle `isShowing` in `ThirdView`. You are better off either dismissing the view or setting the value to `false`. Otherwise, you can get confused what it is doing when you are in your various views.